# Is there a way to update the dashboard developed using dc.js when dc.js version change

Tags: dc.js

Whenever i find the dc.js version changes, i used to manually update the syntax in my code and use the newest version. 
 
Is there a way where the dashboard code need not be touched even the version of dc.js or d3.js version is updated?

Comment: There was one big syntax change between D3v3 and v4, which also caused a lot of changes between dc v2 and v3. This is not expected to happen again.

Comment: I'm already eating my words. [D3 is moving to ES6](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/issues/87) with no transpilation, so it's likely that D3v6 will again break the interface. I hear that there were [codemods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-upgrade-codemod) for easing the transition from D3v3 to D3v4 but we didn't use them for dc v3.

Comment: Very Informative!! Thank You.